# Transactional requests and failure recovery in database systems

Tags: database, transaction

Let's say we deal with a quite naive, simple version of a database, which uses the classic version of redo-undo logs for failure recovery. For a "classic" request transferring an amount from one account to another one, the logs written at each stage of the transaction are the following:

```
1. TRANSACTION START         ----->    START TRANSACTION   XID1
2. READ A1                   ----->    
3. READ A2                   ----->
4. WRITE (A1,A+10)           ----->    WRITE [A1,100,110]  XID1
5. WRITE (A2,A2-10)          ----->    WRITE [A2,200,190]  XID1
6. COMMIT                    ----->    COMMIT TRANSACTION  XID1
```

As an example, if there is a system failure between action 4 & 5, when the database is restarted, it will recognize from the logs that transaction XID1 had not commited and it would proceed with undoing all the writes in the log (using the previous values).

Now, my question. I assume that when reaching action 6, the system first  persists the transaction commit, by writing the COMMIT log and then responds to the client, informing that the request has been processed successfully. In case there is a system failure after the system has written the COMMIT log, but before responding to the client, then what happens ? Following my logic, that would mean that the system after recovering would regard the transaction as committed (since a COMMIT record exists) and would proceed without a need to do any undo-redo. However, the user was probably notified that the transaction was ABORTED, while the transaction was successfully completed.

- Am I missing something in my whole approach ?
- How do common RDBMS systems handle this issue ?

> P.S.: I know that log records are not written immediately to disk actually, but I over-simplified the example for the sake of brevity.

Comment: My DB times are past since a long time, but IIRC there are quite tricky mechanisms that implement a fail over in such a case. But only with those more expensive databases.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol

Comment: FYI, 2PC protocol, you mentioned, is used for distributed systems. My question is about a much simpler, single-server database system.

Comment: You are partially right. The linked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_commit inside is what you are after. Basically 2/3PC is to overcome the shortcomings of atomic commit.

Comment: It sound like you are more concerned with the client application than the database. The database is fine. The client is inconsistent. The usual solution is to make such transactions idempotent: the client will do it again, with no negative side effects.

Comment: The client should not be told that the transaction was ABORTED, because it wasn't.   The client would not know the status of the transaction, and would need to wait for the database to come up again, reconnect,  and see if the transaction occurred or not, before deciding what action to take.

Answer (score 2):

Coming back with a bit of personal research, but still open to any new answers. Naively, one could think that a solution could be to add a new layer of logging (whether the client has received the reply or not). The acknowledgement would have to be built in application-layer, since [TCP does not support something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218785/how-can-i-explicitly-wait-for-a-tcp-ack-before-proceeding). However, we would just have moved the race-condition a bit further, considering that a network partition could lead the client receive the reply, but the server assuming the opposite, rolling back the transaction. As a result, I think this is rooted to the [FLP impossibility theorem](http://the-paper-trail.org/blog/a-brief-tour-of-flp-impossibility/), aka the fact that the server cannot know whether it had previously crashed or the connection was just very very slow (and the message was received on the other side). Briefly, the only approach I came up with for this issue is the following:

- Consider the (server-client) system as a distributed system. In this way, a transaction commit means that the new data are visible and durable to all future reads from all clients (excluding the current transaction). As a result, the client would have to perform a follow-up read, in case the connection was lost to confirm whether the transaction was committed or rolled back. To achieve that, the client operations have to be made idempotent. This approach is nicely described in the [VoltDB's documentation](https://www.voltdb.com/transaction-and-consistency-faq), where it states:

> Note this isn’t really a VoltDB problem, but a problem with any
>   stateful system that uses a network somewhere

Comment: I think that this is exactly correct, particularly with regard to the FLP theorem. It's not possible for the database and the client to be exactly synchronised, so the database commits and tells the client that it has committed. If the client doesn't receive the message, the database doesn't try to care. The client can in theory reconnect after the database recovery and use its own logic to confirm that a transaction successfully committed.